# Sum the installed sizes of packages matching a substring

Tags: debian, awk, grep

I would like to get all the packages that contain the "nvidia" substring in their name, to sum up their size and print the total size in megabytes. 
To do so I have written the following oneliner:

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n | grep nvidia | awk -F' ' '{sum+=$1}END{print sum/1024;}'
```

But, how can I beautify it, make it as short as it is possible to be, keeping the functionality?

It is crooked-written for now, as you can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter using `dpkg-query` itself, which means you don’t need to output the package name, and you don’t need to sort either:

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\n' '*nvidia*' | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum/1024;}'
```